# After putting Bundle into intent it cant be found in the target Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle

I am trying to get arraylist of lists of Locations into another activity but after checking it in the target activity it says null. The code is:

Sending activity:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putSerializable("locations",  locationList);
end.putExtra("locations", args);
```

Receiving activity:

```
Bundle arg = getIntent().getBundleExtra("locations");
locationList = (ArrayList<List<Location>>) arg.getSerializable("locations");
```

Funny thing is that I am using the same principle to get that list into that sending activity from a service in a same way. Although I am sending it from that said service in a broadcast could that be a difference?

Working code:

Sending serivce:

```
Bundle argument = new Bundle();
argument.putSerializable("locationList",locationPoints);
intent.putExtra("locations", argument);
```

Receivng activity:

```
 Bundle argument = intent.getBundleExtra("locations");
 locationList = (ArrayList<List<Location>>) argument.getSerializable("locationList");
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Full methods
I tried using the getSerializableExtra() but that produced the same result.

Sending activity:

```
public void onEnd(View view){

 Intent end = new Intent(this, WorkoutDetailActivity.class);
    end.putExtra("duration", duration);
    end.putExtra("distance", distance);
    end.putExtra("calories", calories);
    end.putExtra("sport", sport);

    for (List<Location> list: locationList){
        for(Location location : list){
            System.out.println(location);
        }
    }

//        Bundle args = new Bundle();
//        args.putSerializable("locationList",  locationList);
    end.putExtra("locations", locationList);


    startActivity(end);
}
```

Receiving activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready 
 to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_maps_workoutmap);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
  locationList = (ArrayList<List<Location>>) 
getIntent().getSerializableExtra("locations");

    System.out.println(locationList);

//        for (List<Location> list: locationList){
//            for(Location location : list){
//                System.out.println(location);
//            }
//        }

}
```

Comment: maybe you need to change "locations" for either locationList or args . ? they both have a same key.

Comment: can you add the part where you build the 'locationPoints' field?

Comment: @Stefan its a mess tbh but the result is fine.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are missing
startactivity(intent);

Comment: No I have it there just didnt include it. The activity starts but i get NullPointerException when trying to getSerializable from bundle.

Comment: Bundle bundle=intent.getParcelableExtra("location");
in receiving activity

Answer (score 0):

Seems no issue as of the code presented. Try changing the key names as both of them says "locations".

If issue still persists, present the entire code snippet of the calling and receiving activites.

UPDATE:

With code snippet:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

if(bundle != null && bundle.getSerializableExtra("locations") != null) {
   locationList = bundle.getSerializableExtra("locations")
}

if(locationList != null) {
   System.out.println(locationList);
}
```

Comment: Try with the snippet provided.

Answer (score 0):

You're using twice the key "locations" in the receiving activity. Once for the bundle extra, then to get your list inside that bundle, but you set up the key to "locationList" in the sending activity :

```
Bundle arg = getIntent().getBundleExtra("locations");
locationList = (ArrayList<List<Location>>) arg.getSerializable("locations"); // => there it should be "locationList"
```

Also, passing a serializable from one activity to another can also be done this way :

Sending Activity :

```
   intent.putExtra("locationList");
```

Receiving Activity :

```
locationList =(ArrayList<List<Location>>)getIntent().getSerializableExtra("locationList");
```

Comment: I am not sure if I am reading something wrong but thats how I have it.

Comment: You do a bit different. You're using a bundle to wrap up your list inside it. I'm saying you can directly pass your list to the intent (instead of passing the serializable to a bundle, then pass the bundle to your intent) so that you can  retrieve it in the receiving activity directly from the intent. Of course, it only works if the bundle you're creating is meant only for your list.

Comment: Yes I see I mean the same key thing but i was looking at the working code. I tried the getSErializableExtra() but it produces the same result.